# Passing Flashvars in Facebook via Open Graph

Tags: facebook, actionscript, flash, flashvars

I'm trying to play my customize video player in my facebook timeline. It loads my custom video player, but it won't pass the clip id to my swf via flashvars. For some reason it keeps returning `NULL`.

Here's the OG tag:

```
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.palpular.com/vp_test.swf?clip_id=1234" />
```

Here's how I tried to load the flashvars:

```
var paramList:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;
var myParam:String = paramList["clip_id"];
```

If I hand code the clip id inside the swf file then the video player plays it.